# Dual seasonal cycles in ts object

Tags: r, time-series, decomposition, stl-decomposition

I want to strip out seasonality from a ts.  This particular ts is daily, and has both yearly and weekly seasonal cycles (frequency 365 and 7).

In order to remove both, I have tried conducting stl() on the ts with frequency set to 365, before extracting trend and remainders, and setting the frequency of the new ts to 7, and repeat.

This doesn't seem to be working very well and I am wondering whether it's my approach, or something inherent to the ts which is causing me problems.  Can anyone critique my methodology, and perhaps recommend an alternate approach?

Answer (score 7):

There is a very easy way to do it using a TBATS model implemented in the `forecast` package. Here is an example assuming your data are stored as `x`:

```
library(forecast)
x2 <- msts(x, seasonal.periods=c(7,365))
fit <- tbats(x2)
x.sa <- seasadj(fit)
```

Details of the model are described in [De Livera, Hyndman and Snyder (JASA, 2011)](http://robjhyndman.com/papers/complex-seasonality/).

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, Rob.  Your forecast package is the best, and it looks as though I've only scratched the surface.  The seasadj(fit) line in your answer returns an error which I am struggling to interpret, perhaps you could help?  "Error in `[.default`(comp, , "season") : subscript out of bounds"

Comment: Can you send me a minimal example to replicate the error? This functionality is relatively new and not well-tested. It worked on the example I tried. Send bug reports to https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/issues?state=open

Answer (score 2):

An approach that can handle not only seasonal components (cyclically reoccurring events) but also trends (slow shifts in the norm) admirably is `stl()`, specifically as implemented by Rob J Hyndman.

The `decomp` function Hyndman gives there (reproduced below) is very helpful for checking for `seasonality` and then `decomposing` a time series into seasonal (if one exists), `trend`, and `residual` components.

```
decomp <- function(x,transform=TRUE)
{
  #decomposes time series into seasonal and trend components
  #from http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/tscharacteristics/
  require(forecast)
  # Transform series
  if(transform & min(x,na.rm=TRUE) >= 0)
  {
    lambda <- BoxCox.lambda(na.contiguous(x))
    x <- BoxCox(x,lambda)
  }
  else
  {
    lambda <- NULL
    transform <- FALSE
  }
  # Seasonal data
  if(frequency(x)>1)
  {
    x.stl <- stl(x,s.window="periodic",na.action=na.contiguous)
    trend <- x.stl$time.series[,2]
    season <- x.stl$time.series[,1]
    remainder <- x - trend - season
  }
  else #Nonseasonal data
  {
    require(mgcv)
    tt <- 1:length(x)
    trend <- rep(NA,length(x))
    trend[!is.na(x)] <- fitted(gam(x ~ s(tt)))
    season <- NULL
    remainder <- x - trend
  }
  return(list(x=x,trend=trend,season=season,remainder=remainder,
    transform=transform,lambda=lambda))
}
```

As you can see it uses `stl()` (which uses `loess`) if there is seasonality and penal­ized regres­sion splines if there is no seasonality.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is useful:
`Start and End Values depends on your Data - Change the Frequency values accordingly`

```
splot <- ts(Data1, start=c(2010, 2), end=c(2013, 9), frequency=12)
```

`additive trend, seasonal, and irregular components can be decomposed using the stl() Function`

```
fit <- stl(splot, s.window="period")
monthplot(splot) 
library(forecast)
vi <-seasonplot(splot)
```

**vi** should give seperate values for a seasonal indices

Also Check the below one:

```
splot.stl <- stl(splot,s.window="periodic",na.action=na.contiguous)
    trend <- splot.stl$time.series[,2]
    season <- splot.stl$time.series[,1]
    remainder <- splot - trend - season
```